# Unicode safe find using boost and standard C++

Tags: c++, boost, unicode

Consider the following snippet:

```
namespace bl = boost::locale;
static bl::generator gen;
static auto loc = gen("en_US.UTF-8");
std::string foo8 = u8"Föo";
std::string deco = bl::normalize(foo8,bl::norm_nfd,loc);
std::string comp = bl::normalize(foo8,bl::norm_nfc,loc);
std::cout << "decomposed: " << deco.find("o") << ", composed: " << comp.find("o") <<"\n";
```

This gives:  "decomposed: 1, composed: 3".

Now, the correct answer depends on the collation factor, but for most cases the latter would be what I want -- the first location of an o, not the first part of a decomposed ö.  Obviously for this example I can normalize a string to NFC to ensure I get the desired result, but this won't work for cases where a grapheme-cluster can't be composed.

Further, X.find("ö") will have implementation defined behavior, as there are no guarantees how that ö is encoded in the search.

I can implement a Unicode safe find function by implementing the algorithm in UAX 29, or by normalizing the search strings, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this by using the C++ std library and boost -- perhaps by combining a locale with a string algorithm -- but I haven't found a solution.

Anyone have a definitive answer?  I'm aware that I could use ICU, and that boost::locale is a c++ friendly wrapper around the ICU library (at least it is if you want full unicode support).

Comment: a number got cut off from the sample output

Comment: It's a definite "no" with the standard library. Would you consider ICU?

Comment: I see [tag:boost], boost::locale and [tag:unicode]. I assume icu is already a dependency there

Comment: ICU is a dependancy, and I can live with that (sort of), but I'd rather not have to work with ICU -- although I could implement a wrapper function if needs be.  ICU's interface is quite horrible from a C++ perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Further, `X.find("ö")` will have implementation defined behavior, as there are no guarentees how that ö is encoded in the search.

Sadly, there really isn't much you can do about this. As a client of the API you have to ensure you always call it using the `u8` prefix and that the argument is also normalized. One could write a `find` function that normalizes the input prior to searching, but there's no way to mitigate the ambiguity in the encoding.

> I can implement a Unicode safe find function by implementing the algorithm in UAX 29

There's no need to implement it since it is already implemented by Boost.Locales `segment_index`.

> I'm wondering if there is a way to do this by using the C++ std library and boost -- perhaps by combining a locale with a string algorithm -- but I haven't found a solution.

The standard library is borderline useless for this and as far as I know Boost.Locale doesn't have string search facilities. ICU's string search functionality uses the notion of canonical equivalence and that's probably your best bet.

Comment: Whoops, I screwed up writing that question.  It should have read "but this won't work where a grapheme-cluster can't be *composed*.  I've corrected this and the error in the code copy-pase.   Your answer r.e. UAX 29 seems to be the winner though -- this should allow me to write a unicode safe, non-transforming find without all the manual labor of coding UAX 29's tables,  which is the end goal.  I'll verify this before accepting the answer.

Comment: Sadly segment_index isn't really suitable to my purpose, since using it to implement a unicode aware find would make my performance unacceptable.  Still, clearly the best answer I'm going to get.  I have edited your answer to reflect the correction I made to my question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yeah, I really wish I had something better for you, but there's not a lot of choice :(